# How to attach image in email from drawable in android

Tags: android

I am attaching an image from drawable folder and sending it in a email.
when  I send it from default email client.Image extension(.png) is missing in attachment
and and also the file name is changed itself.
I want t send image with default name(as in drawable) and with .png extension.

this is my code.

```
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.setType("image/png");

            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });

            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hey! ");


            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Sending........"));
```

Please suggest me what is worng in this code 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only attach an image to mail if the image is located in the SDCARD.
So, you'll need to copy the image to SD and then attach it.

```
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try
{
in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ic_launcher);
out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.png"));
copyFile(in, out);
 in.close();
 in = null;
 out.flush();
out.close();
out = null;
}
catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }


Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("text/html");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "File attached");
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.png"));
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: @Givi how to attach image of drawable?